# Where is a package org.eclipse.jdt.core.refactoring.descriptors

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-jdt

I want to use org.eclipse.jdt.ui.refactoring.RenameSupport class

```
RenameSupport renameSupport = RenameSupport.create(packageFragment, newName,
                    RenameSupport.UPDATE_REFERENCES);
```

Here I get an error "*The type org.eclipse.jdt.core.refactoring.descriptors.RenameJavaElementDescriptor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files*".
It looks weird. I thought it should be in the same jar. Help says that RenameJavaElementDescriptors declared in the package org.eclipse.jdt.core.refactoring.descriptors. But I cannot find this package. Where I can find it? Eclipse 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you are looking for is in **org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation** project.